# problems with twitter button in html table

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Can someone explain why trying to place a tweet button in the following section of HTML doesn't work.  No button is appearing but a hyperlink is.  However, when clicked on, it loads up the Twitter page but with none of the details specified in the hyperlink.  The data comes from the Guardian API.

```
function updateTable(results) {

clearTable();

var table = document.getElementById("newsResults");
  for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    var row=table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);    
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6=row.insertCell(5);



    cell1.textContent = results[i]["webPublicationDate"].substring(0,10);
    cell2.textContent = results[i]["webPublicationDate"].substring(11,19);
    cell3.textContent = results[i]["sectionName"]
    cell4.textContent = results[i]["webTitle"];
    cell5.innerHTML = "<a href='"+ results[i]["webUrl"] + "' target='_blank'>"+results[i]["webUrl"] + "</a>";
    cell6.value = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button" data-via="your_screen_name" data-lang="en" data-related="anywhereTheJavascriptAPI" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>'


      }
}

 !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

I can get the Twitter Button to appear when it's placed outside of the table

This is it in full: http://jsfiddle.net/XX8PW/

Comment: You should post the relevant HTML snippet.

Comment: Added JS Fiddle with the code

Comment: Instead of `cell6.value =` try `cell6.innerHTML`, then you also need to move the Twitter JS inside the function.

Comment: It's still not showing the tweet button in the Tweet column.  Plus none of the information is being passed to the tweet when clicked on. http://jsfiddle.net/XX8PW/1/

Comment: Check this, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woqcJ (Doesn't seem to work in FF, but that's not a problem with the code) - works in Chrome, IE11 etc.

Comment: Basically the idea is, if you're adding the button dynamically, you need to re-initialise the Twitter javascript when you update.

Comment: So how would you do that given the current context in the code?  I thought being placed in the for loop would be enough. Haven't used much of Twitter before I'm afraid